# What kind of index would be efficient when there is IN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Here is my query:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE type = 4 AND author_id IN (?, ?) AND post_id IN (?, ?)
```

And here is all my current indexes:

```
(id)  -- PK
(author_id, seen)
(author_id, date_time)
(type, other_id, author_id)
(comment_id, type, author_id)
```

Well, Should I add any new index for query above?

Comment: This answer will depend strongly on your data.  Unfortunately, there's no one-size-fits-all answer when it comes to Indexing.  Schema, data, data distribution, how you're calling the statement, etc... all of those things should be considered when determining your Index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess an index on `type` would probably be the only useful one; because `A IN (B, C, D)` translates to `A = B OR A = C OR A = D`, and MySQL seems to ignore indices once it encounters an `OR`.

Alternatively, make/execute four copies of the query with the possible combinations of `author_id` and `post_id`; but unless it is a drastic performance issue I probably would not recommend it.

Comment: Ah ok, then should I remove `type` from those multiple column indexes groups?

Comment: An index on, or starting with, `type` would be the only useful one as far as I know.

Comment: Well currently I have a index like this `(type, other_id, author_id)`. Is that enough?

Comment: It should help, but as Kalmino's comment indicated, the benefits of indices greatly depends on actual data. Ex: If your table is millions of rows, and 90% of those rows are `type = 4` it will still help, but not as much as if only 10% were type 4 with twice as many total rows.

Comment: You know, I don't know English very well and still I cannot understand this sentence of your answer : *"and MySQL seems to ignore indices once it encounters an `OR`."* May you please rephrase it?

Comment: Indexes are often ignored by MySQL when the list of conditions contains an `OR`, such as a query with `WHERE a = 3 OR a = 5` can often be processed faster as a UNION of the form `SELECT * FROM A WHERE a = 3 UNION SELECT * FROM A WHERE a = 5;`. _...but `WHERE a = 3 AND (b = 3 or b = 5)` may still benefit from an index on `a`._

Comment: I see, just do you mean `UNION` form is faster that `OR` form? Or vica virsa ?

Comment: UNION is faster than OR; but it becomes impractical to maintain with more than a few values, since it basically requires synchronizing changes to multiple copies of a marginally simpler query any time the query must be modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(type, author_id)
INDEX(type, post_id)
```

Those have `type` first because it is compared `= constant`.  Then they have one `IN` clause.  Newer versions of MySQL will efficiently "leapfrog" ("MRR") through the `IN` set.  I don't think they can do two `INs`.

The optimizer will look at statistics and choose which of those two indexes is likely to be better.

Still, it *may* be possible that `INDEX(type, other_id, author_id)` will be beneficial.  What version of MySQL are you running?  Can you do `EXPLAIN DELETE ...` to see how it is likely to perform the query?  If you see "ICP" or "Index condition pushdown" or "Using index condition", that will be better.  (That depends on a relatively new optimization.)