# Using OR operator VS UNION operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries: *(they have identical results)*. The only difference between them is using `OR` vs `UNION ALL` ..!

First:

```
. . . WHERE h.id = :id1 OR h.related = :id2 . . .
```

Second:

```
. . . FROM ((select q.* from quanda q where q.id = :id1) UNION ALL
            (select q.* from quanda q where q.related = :id2)
           ) LEFT JOIN . . .
```

I heard using `UNION` would be much faster .. But tests show me using `OR` is much faster. Why? I've done it wrong?

---

### First:

```
SELECT h.id, 
       h.subject,
       h.body matnF,
       h.amount,
       h.keywords tags,
       h.closed,
       h.author_id author,
       h.AcceptedAnswer,
       h.type,
       h.visibility,
       h.date_time,
       v.value AS vote_value,
       u.reputation,
       u.user_fname,
       u.user_lname,
       u.avatar,
       (h.author_id = 29) as hasUserId,
       (select COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0) from votes vv
        where h.id = vv.post_id and vv.table_code = 15) as total_votes,
       (select count(1) from favorites ff
        where h.type = 0 and h.id = ff.post_id and ff.table_code = 15) as total_fav,
       CASE WHEN h.type = 1 THEN '0'
            WHEN h.amount IS NULL OR h.author_id = 29 THEN '1'
            ELSE EXISTS (select 1 from money m
                          where m.user_id = 29 and m.post_id = h.id)
       END paid,
       CASE WHEN h.type = 0 AND f.id IS NOT NULL THEN '2' ELSE '3'
       END AS favorite
FROM qanda h
LEFT JOIN votes v
     ON h.id = v.post_id AND v.user_id = 29 AND v.table_code = 15
LEFT JOIN favorites f
     ON h.type = 0 AND h.id = f.post_id AND f.user_id = 29 AND f.table_code = 15
LEFT JOIN users u
     ON h.author_id = u.id and h.visibility = 1
WHERE h.id = 9 OR h.related = 9                            -- this
ORDER BY h.type, h.AcceptedAnswer DESC, h.date_time
```

**`EXPLAIN`'s result:**

[image]

**Benchmark:**

time execution for a small dataset *(a table with 30 rows)* - *(for 500 times run)*: 1.739413022995

---

### Second:

```
SELECT h.id, 
       h.subject,
       h.body matnF,
       h.amount,
       h.keywords tags,
       h.closed,
       h.author_id author,
       h.AcceptedAnswer,
       h.type,
       h.visibility,
       h.date_time,
       v.value AS vote_value,
       u.reputation,
       u.user_fname,
       u.user_lname,
       u.avatar,
       (h.author_id = 29) as hasUserId,
       (select COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0) from votes vv
        where h.id = vv.post_id and vv.table_code = 15) as total_votes,
       (select count(1) from favorites ff
        where h.type = 0 and h.id = ff.post_id and ff.table_code = 15) as total_fav,
       CASE WHEN h.type = 1 THEN '0'
            WHEN h.amount IS NULL OR h.author_id = 29 THEN '1'
            ELSE EXISTS (select 1 from money m
                          where m.user_id = 29 and m.post_id = h.id)
       END paid,
       CASE WHEN h.type = 0 AND f.id IS NOT NULL THEN '2' ELSE '3'
       END AS favorite
FROM ((SELECT q.* FROM qanda q WHERE q.id = 9)                -- this
        UNION ALL
      (SELECT q.* FROM qanda q WHERE q.related = 9)
     ) h
LEFT JOIN votes v
     ON h.id = v.post_id AND v.user_id = 29 AND v.table_code = 15
LEFT JOIN favorites f
     ON h.type = 0 AND h.id = f.post_id AND f.user_id = 29 AND f.table_code = 15
LEFT JOIN users u
     ON h.author_id = u.id and h.visibility = 1
ORDER BY h.type, h.AcceptedAnswer DESC, h.date_time
```

**`EXPLAIN`'s result:**

[image]

**Benchmark:**

time execution for a small dataset *(a table with 30 rows)* - *(for 500 times run)*: 15.66437292099

Comment: You cannot judge performance based on small data set.

Comment: Please format your query, I can't see whats happening

Comment: @1000111 is correct.  All your data is on a single data page, so scanning the table should be very fast.  There is additional overhead for reading the table twice and saving the results as a derived table.

Comment: Don't know where you heard UNION was faster. Can you post a link to where you *heard* that?

Comment: UNION ALL is only faster under certain conditions like if the or conditions will required more then an index seek (for example if you use an or depending on 2 different tables). You cannot say in general that UNION ALL is faster then OR. If you do something like SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRIMKEY = 1 OR PRIMKEY = 2 it will be faster then a union all of both.

Comment: @KenWhite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709117/what-kind-of-index-would-be-efficient-when-there-is-in-clause#comment62899928_37709183

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I use `OR`, MySQL is executing an *index_merge* on the `related` and the `primary` key .. Isn't that better than using `UNION` instead?

Comment: This feels like premature optimization. I would try to avoid such performance hacks where you try to second guess the optimizer. These behaviors can change with different releases so should not really be depended on. Much better to play by the rules and optimize with table design and indexes.

Comment: Ah, so you based your entire knowledge of the topic on a single comment made by a single user in a single thread. Got it. Clearly an expert analysis was involved. :-) The user in question doesn't even have 5K rep here, either. And you selectively read the first few words in that comment and ignored the rest.

Comment: I also don't think I'd take as gospel something that someone says in a comment on here.

Comment: @TomH Do you mean what he said is wrong and `OR` is better than `UNION`?

Comment: @KenWhite That ^ ?

Comment: I mean the same as several others have said (including @Gordon, who is much more knowledgeable in this area than the comment poster), which is that there is no general *this is better than that **always*** answer. It depends on the data involved and the query being run. There is seldom a *one size fits all* answer, any more than there is a *one size fits all* car. Which is more suitable depends on benchmarking the two against your **specific** needs and data and determining which is better **in that particular case**, the same as when you're optimizing anything else.

Comment: @KenWhite I see, also yes Gordon is perfect in database subjects. Actually I asked this question because [Gordon suggested me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723716/how-to-replace-or-operator-with-union-operator#37723799) to use `UNION` instead of `OR` ..! But tests tell me `OR` is faster ..! What would you do if you were in my place?

Comment: Does repeating it again help? *Benchmark the two against your specific needs and data to determine which is better **in this particular case***, and use that one **in this particular case**.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok Gordon there you go: [A huge dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729731/can-mysql-use-indexes-when-there-is-or-between-conditions) but still `OR` is faster than `UNION`.

Comment: @Stack . . . How selective are the conditions?  That is, how many rows are in `qanda` and how many does the `where` condition select.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see what's your point. Actually there is 10,000 rows in `qanda` table and the `where` condition selects 3 rows. But still using `OR` is faster than `UNION`. However I know why: in this case, `index_merge` optimization is being used and the query is actually executed by unioning results from the two indexes `Using union(PRIMARY, related)`. So no need to an `UNION` in the query.

Comment: @Stack . . . The index merge optimization is very powerful . . . but not used sufficiently often.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see. Just as you see, in this case it uses index merge. So can I use `OR` safely? Or still are you believe I should use `UNION` instead of `OR` in this case?

Comment: Check the `explain` plan to see if the query uses the indexes properly for the `or`.